# Django user model post save breaking unit test login

Tags: django, django-signals

This signal seems to be breaking my unit tests for login. I'm not sure why?

**Signal**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    post_save.disconnect(update_profile, sender=User)
    if Profile.objects.filter(user=instance).exists():
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=instance)
        if instance.first_name:
            profile.first_name = instance.first_name
        if instance.last_name:
            profile.last_name = instance.last_name
        if instance.email:
            profile.email = instance.email

        profile.save()
        post_save.connect(update_profile, sender=User)

post_save.connect(update_profile, sender=User)
```

**Unit Test**

```
class AdminProfileUpdate(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = create_user(password='foobar')
        self.profile = self.user.get_or_create_profile
        self.client = Client()

    def test_profile_base_template(self)
        logged_in = self.client.login(username=self.user.username,
                password='foobar')
        self.assertTrue(logged_in)
```

Comment: Please post your **actual** code. Everything we need to reproduce. Don't post code that has obvious bugs or that don't compile (e.g. missing imports).

Comment: Why do you disconnect the signal and then reconnect it? Why not just leave it connected? (And why do you leave the signal disconnected if the profile doesn't exist?)

Comment: Ahh... This is my stupid. The bug has nothing to do with the signal. In my profile model, I am saving the same fields to the User model so there was some funky recursion going on. How can I close this question?

Comment: Explain your solution in an answer and then mark that answer as accepted. (However, I bet the signal stuff is in fact relevant: I presume you had to disconnect the signal because saving the Profile instance causes the User instance to be saved too, which would invoke the signal recursively. So the signal disconnection is evidence that you had encountered the recursion before and tried to work around it instead of fixing it.)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `save()` in post-save handler does look as an unfortunate solution to me. Did you try to override the `save` instead? Like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do the instance changes you want to be saved as well
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # do the save operation
        # update anything else, if you want to
```